# Zone Normal range in system with 4G RAM

Tags: linux, memory, 64bit

I have a 4GB RAM in my system. Following is my BIOS provided RAM map.

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009d7ff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d800-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
.
.
.
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed1ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000011fdfffff] usable
```

The last line gives a range greater than 4G and it is mapped as Zone NORMAL.

```
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x00001000-0x00ffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x01000000-0xffffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x100000000-0x11fdfffff]
```

Output of  cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:        3955304 kB
MemFree:         1878108 kB
MemAvailable:    2182668 kB
```

Where is this 510MB coming from? Or is my system is installed with 4.5 G?

I am using a 64 bit arch linux running 3.16.3.

Help with reference material is also fine.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow which 510MB you are referring to.

Comment: The range [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000011fdfffff] . I am referring to Zone Normal.

Comment: Some graphics cards have their own RAM, which is typically mapped above the main board RAM. I don't know if that's what your're seeing. Some other kernel logs should give more information.